# Trapezoidal tab with borders

Tags: css, tabs, border, shapes, styling

So, I have made this trapezoid shape tab. But when i want to select it and set color to white and blue border, it keeps cutting my side borders. I know that this is because of `clip-path: polygon(1% 0, 99% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);` that I put in css class to give me that shape.

My question is, is there any other way that i can cut sides or get similar trapezoid effect, but to have selected tab in white color and visible border on all sides?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like so:

CSS:

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

You can play around with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfzed0bj/)

Comment: Is there any way to use percents and not pixels, because app is responsive and it would span from 1024 up to 1920 in width?

Comment: You can change the width to %  but you would have to leave the border-left and right as pixels

Comment: Cool...i could use that since i don't change height. Thanks man

Comment: But ...I still can't have all borders visible ...left and right are transparent, and i want to have them all visible, practically same as on picture but with left and right ...